# How to change the default window size of an outside process?

Tags: vb.net

This is a program in vb.net, but I'm planning to use an outside process by using system.diagnostics.process.start("C:\Otherprogram.exe")
Now what I want to do is to resize the default size of window of outside process, can I do that?So that only the things that will be needed by the user can be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to start the process with a minimized, maximized or normal window (by setting the ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle and using the Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method). However, you don't really have control over the size of the window of the outside process when you start it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you launch the the program, you can get it's main window handle using [Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx).

Given the window handle, you should be able to [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html) [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) to position or size that window.

Comment: I started writing this, but on re-reading the OP wants to change the *default* window size with which otherprogram.exe *creates* its main window.  By the time MainWindowHandle is available, otherprogram.exe may already have shown its window at the "wrong" size, resulting in a nasty visual glitch.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, this is (I believe) the best you can do, though. (Without control over the other program's code...)